# Looking for a windows 7 / vista like xfwm4 theme

Tags: xfce

Anyone know where I can find a window 7 like xfwm4 theme, that will work with my Windows like icon theme and GTK styles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these themes, they are the closest to the Windows Aero theme I could find

http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/LiNstaBF?content=78628

http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/LiNsta+Black+Plastic?content=43023

Answer (score 1):

Now there also is this window theme:

http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/X-Aero+%28XFWM4+Windows+7+%2B+Vista+Theme%29?content=170901